# Tomcat 7 performance ISSUES (WIN 7 x64)

Tags: java, mysql, performance, apache, tomcat

I have Apache Tomcat 7 running on Win 7 x64 (using jdk_1.8.), running web application which corporate with MYSQL database. When size of devices which needs to be requested (TCP/IP) increase - some of devices do not respond promptly - Apache starts to have issues with performance. I've read that changing settings of database doesn't really matter, although it is already prepared to deal with huge projects. So assuming that it is not database fault, I have still troubles with tomcat settings. 
In server.xml ( ~\apache\conf\server.xml) I have followng settings:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           maxThreads="1000" minSpareThreads="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           acceptCount="500"
           redirectPort="8443"
           compression="on"  
           compressionMinSize="2048"  
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"  
           compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
           />
```

Java JRE settings:
-Xms8192m -Xms16384 -Xss512k

In Tomcat I have following settings:
http://fotoo.pl/show.php?img=899435_1.png.html

Print screen from Apache Tomcat 7 generating many exceptions and warning because pool size is still to small and some requests must be refused 
http://fotoo.pl/show.php?img=899437_bezntytu-u.png.html

My question is how to set those settings ( in server.xml and in Apache Tomcat Properties ) if I have machine dedicated to run only this server and I have 32GB CACHE memory, Proccessor Intel Core i7-4930K 3.30 GHz and SSD disks to improve preformance of my Tomcat.

If you need to get any additional information to answer my question do not afraid to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Take it: Windows is not the best OS for serving WebApps. Quite the contrary. The file systems are outright horrible ( both NTFS and ReFS are around 20% slower than an *untuned* ext4 or xfs). Then you have the RAM overhead for the GUI. And the crazy memory management based on the idea that unused RAM is good RAM (because processes might request some in the future) and therefor it actively pages out to keep as much physical RAM as possible free.

The acceptcount value does not make sense, too: putting a lot of requests into a queue does not help increasing the performance. It just hides the actual problems. Set it to a low value, as this is only meant to give a small buffer for peaks. Plus, it eats up RAM for the processes doing the jobs.

Maxthreads means that up to 1k connections might be opened to your DB, too. I assume here is the bottleneck. Plus: if you have 1k concurrent users, that means that there are only 16MB of RAM for each user available (yeah, rough calculation, but it makes the point obvious). Depending on your application, expect a concurrent user to need much more. I have seen applications where the RAM / concurrent user was exceeding 200MB.

So all in all I'd say that you have to both scale up and out.

*Totally biased note: If the machine is dedicated, use GNU/Linux or Unix.*

Comment: Dear Mark, Thing is that I PLC software which runs only on WIN so it is impossible to exchange operation system on Linux ( despite of fact that I have medium experience in administarting this kind of platform). So in this case, changing whole construction of application can not be applied. All the best.

Comment: Tweaking the _values_ I mentioned has nothing to do wether you run Tomcat on Windows or Linux.